# Rich Push Notifications not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios

I did the whole setup from [here](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/push-notifications/rich-notifications.html):

1. Im using MarketingCloudSDK iOS v7.5.0 with Cocoapods
2. Service Extension has been added with the code from the example
3. Code signing is using the same Apple DEVELOPMENT TEAM as the main project
4. SFMC Dashboard got the Rich Notifications set on, so I'm sending images. I can see the userInfo and the "_mediaUrl" String from the Notification.
5. The Push arrives to the user, I can see it in my device... without the image.

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed:

I downloaded the Learning App and I compared my pp to search for problems.

[image]

This was missing.